# I can't add new record in jQuery EasyUI editable datagrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datagrid

I use jQuery EasyUI editable datagrid to display data from a mySQL database.
At the top of the table is a button-toolbar for adding a new row in the tablegrid.
The first time i click the button, only a new row appears but I cannot add any new data.
When I click the button again, a second row appears an now I can enter the data like it should be.

How can i avoid this?

the code for the button is:

```
<a id="<?php print $toolbar_id; ?>_btn_1" 
    href="javascript:void(0)" 
    class="easyui-linkbutton" 
    iconCls="icon-add" 
    plain="true" 
    onclick="javascript:$('#<?php print $grid_id;?>').edatagrid('addRow',{ index: 2, row:{mid:'1'} })" 
    disabled="true">
        Actie toevoegen
</a>
```

The button is enabled when selecting a row in the parent tablegrid.

**UPDATE**

```
<div id="actieplan">
    <h2>Actieplan</h2>
    <p style="margin-left: 20px; font-style: italic;"><?php $l->__('geen melding geselecteerd');?></p>
    <table id="<?php print $grid_id;?>"           
           title="Acties" 
           style="height:auto;"
           toolbar="#<?php print $toolbar_id; ?>" 
           >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th field="id" sortable="true" >#</th>
                <th field="melding_id" width="10" sortable="true" hidden>#bom</th>
                <th field="human_datum" width="40" editor="{type:'datebox',options:{
                    required:true}
                    }" sortable="true">Datum</th>
                <th field="human_datum_start" width="40" editor="{type:'datebox',options:{required:false}}" sortable="true">Startdatum</th>
                <th field="human_datum_eind" width="40" editor="{type:'datebox',options:{required:false}}" sortable="true">Einddatum</th>
                <th field="actie" width="200" editor="{type:'validatebox',options:{required:true}}">Actie</th>

                <th field="uitvoerder_naam" width="100" editor="{
                    type:'combobox', options:{
                        required:true,
                        url:'./model/actie/lst_uitvoerders_acties.php',
                        valueField:'uitvoerder_naam',
                        textField: 'uitvoerder_naam',
                        panelHeight:'auto'}
                    }" sortable="true">Uitvoerder</th>
                <th field="status_id" width="50" editor="{type:'combobox', options:{
                        required:true,
                        url:'./model/status/lst_status.php',
                        valueField:'id',
                        textField:'status',
                        panelHeight:'auto'}
                    }" sortable="true">Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Comment: can you please add addtional info? Without any code we can't help you..

Comment: the code for the button is             <a id="<?php print $toolbar_id; ?>_btn_1" href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-add" plain="true" 
               onclick="javascript:$('#<?php print $grid_id;?>').edatagrid('addRow',{
                    index: 2,
                    row:{mid:'1'}
        })" disabled="true">Actie toevoegen</a>
The button is enabled when selecting a row in the parent tablegrid.

Comment: I just make changes in demo on easyUI site accoarding to you button value it work correctly look at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dQMf/). So the problem not in button. Can you share code for table creation?

Comment: I solved the problem with a function addActie().
Maybe the you can't add a row with an inherited value from an other object?